# How to evolve a dataclass in python?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm interested to use dataclass as the syntax is shorter than attr. However I can't find a shortcut that provides the API to evolve it, using e.g. the following code:

```
@dataclass
class AB(object):
    a: int = 1
    b: int = 2

AB().evolve(b=3)

result = AB(a=1, b=3)
```

Is it easy to find an out-of-the-box replacement? or to implement it on my own?

Comment: Here's a link to a really good youtube video titled [Dataclasses - The code generator to end all code generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw) by the core Python developer Raymond Hettinger about them that should help.

Comment: Your exemplary usage of `evolve` here is a little odd, since it is not an instance method in attrs and is called [straight from the module](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.evolve) with the instance as the first argument. Either way, Xukrao's answer seems on point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`dataclasses.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.replace) function is roughly equivalent to the [`attr.evolve()`](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html#attr.evolve) function.

Usage example based on your code:

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class AB(object):
    a: int = 1
    b: int = 2


ab_object = AB()
another_ab_object = dataclasses.replace(ab_object, b=3)

print(ab_object)
# Output: AB(a=1, b=2)
print(another_ab_object)
# Output: AB(a=1, b=3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The different standard in python is really confusing

Comment: @tribbloid `dataclasses` are [standard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), `attrs` aren't at all.